# How do I change servers in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I've seen posts about people changing what server they're playing on (eg. US1 or US2), but I've clicked around everywhere in the game and I don't see an option for it.

Where do I find the option to select which server to play on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the launcher, there is a button in the lower left corner.  This allows you to change server.

[image: lower left corner of launcher]

Comment: As a side-note, once you have launched the game, you must exit completely in order to change servers.